# C# Call function everytime Form is loaded

Tags: c#, forms

I want my program to execute a specific function everytime the form is run.
The function would be to get the baseAdress of a process.
Current code:

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Adicionar());

            if (getmodule()) {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(baseAdress)); //Dunno if this is going to work but it's just to see if it's getting a baseAdress;
                adress d = new adress();
                d.Adress = (0x6C7FC + baseAdress + 0xA82020);
            }
 }
      static bool getmodule(){ .... }
```

how would that be possible to make?

Comment: Did this even successfully build?

Comment: @Yaman No- `CS0120` is a compiler error.

Comment: Yeah, a staitc method can be called without an object (on the class level) so there is no object when you are inside it, you have to declare getmodule static to refer to it.

Comment: Ok, that's one part of the problem solved, but how do I make the function getmodule() get called everytime someone runs the program? As I need to have the baseAdress as soon as the programs loads

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see that `main` is a static method, you can't call a non static method from a static method, if you want to call meas you have to make it as a static otherwise need an instance under the scope, So make it as static method:

```
  static bool getmodule()
  {    
    // do somethong here 
  }
```